# Euler 8- adjacent digits

Tags: c

I am trying to project Euler problem 8 but, I have a problem.
The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

```
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
```

Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

and my code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char ar[] =
    "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\
    96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\
    85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\
    12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\
    66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\
    62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\
    30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\
    70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\
    65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\
    52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\
    53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\
    83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\
    82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\
    16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\
    17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\
    24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\
    07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\
    84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\
    05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\
    71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

    int i, j;
    long long int max=0;
    long long int count = 1;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(ar)-14;i++){//null
        for(j=i;j<i+13;j++){
            count = ((int)ar[j]-48) * count;
        }
        if(max<count) {max=count;}
        count = 1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", max);
}
```

my answer is incorrect. (my answer is 268435456)
i guess for loop's problem.

Comment: Note: you can do this in linear time instead of quadratic by having a single loop that 1) divides your current product by the value of the first digit in the substring currently under consideration, 2) increments the pointer to the next substring, and 3) multiplies the result of (1) by the value of the new last digit. You need a little more work before the first iteration, but overall that will be more efficient...

Comment: Your `max` is a `long long`, which should be big enough to hold the product on most platforms. But you cut it short by printing it as a normal `int` with `%d`. You need the `%lld` format. (You could as well make it `unsigned lon long`, for which you'd need `%llu`.)

Comment: I guess because the question shows no research effort

Comment: @anatolyg I will effort researching(but i can't english well... T.T)

Comment: @twalberg, good point, but you will find a zero in substrings and will loose your accumulated product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a glance, I see two problems.

Firstly — this:

```
    "foo\
    bar\
    baz"
```

is equivalent to this:

```
   "foo    bar    baz"
```

because the `\` only quotes the newline, not the indentation afterward.

What you want is this:

```
    "foo"
    "bar"
    "baz"
```

which is equivalent to this:

```
    "foobarbaz"
```

because the C compiler will concatenate adjacent string literals.

Secondly — as [M Oehm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2979617/m-oehm) points out in a comment above: to print your `long long` result, you need to use `%lld` rather than `%d`. *[Note: an earlier version of this answer talked about `int` vs. `int64_t`, but that's because I was looking at the wrong line. Sorry!]*

Comment: Two good points. The problem is not the data type - OP uses `long long`, which will be 64 bits on most mopdern systems. The wrong printing format truncates the answer, though.

Comment: @MOehm: Yeah, I just saw your comment to the question. You are quite right. Edited, thanks!